# Kurento - Magic Mirror example Error Code : 40108

Tags: kurento

I'm running the MagicMirror sample app, with no changes, and I get the following error:  Media Object not available (Code:40108, Type:null).  KMS is running, so I'm not sure what's wrong.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the directory `/var/lib/kurento/.cache/gstreamer-1.5` and restart your service:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/kurento/.cache/gstreamer-1.5
sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 restart
```

The problem is that some updates break gstreamer cache for some unknown reason and this re-generates it correctly.

**Edit**

You may also need to update gstreamer plugins correctly:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: The directory  /var/lib/kurento  doesn't exist.

Comment: Deleted from /var/kurento/.cache/gstreamer-1.5, and I still ran into the same problem.  Restarted both KMS, and Ubuntu.  Tried again on a fresh install of everything including Ubuntu, and it seems to be working now.  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the reply with more details, just for the records.